# Defining unnamed class member functions?

Tags: c++, class, definition, member-functions

I currently have two unnamed classes defined in my Foo.h:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();

    class {
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
    public:
        int GetX() { return x; }
        int GetY() { return y; }
    } Sub1;

    class {
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        int GetX() { return x; }
    } Sub2;
}
```

This code compiles just fine, and it used like this:

```
 Foo temp;
 int Ax, Ay, Bx;
 Ax = temp.Sub1.GetX();
 Ay = temp.Sub1.GetY();
 Bx = temp.Sub2.GetX();
```

However, now I want to move the member function definitions to the source file.The only way I know to split this class into a header file and source file, is to name the classes:

Foo.h:

```
class Foo {

private:    
    class A {
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
    public:
        int GetX();
        int GetY();
    };

    class B {
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        int GetX();
    };

public:
    Foo();
    A Sub1;
    B Sub2;

}
```

Foo.cpp:

```
int Foo::A::GetX() { return x; }
int Foo::A::GetY() { return y; }
int Foo::B::GetX() { return x; }
```

This code is not what I want, however, since it is ugly and I didn't want a named class in the first place.

Is it possible to split the class into a header file and source file? Or is this just bad code design?

Comment: Consider using structs if Sub1 and Sub2 are just going to be data members of Foo.  Then you could remove the need for Get functions as well.

Comment: If your internal classes become more than ``struct``s, you might consider moving them out of the class and into a private ``namespace``.

Comment: If you use the unnamed inner classes, how does the compiler know which `GetX` function to use?  You can't refer by class name, since there aren't any.

Comment: The actual code was simplified for the purpose of demonstrating my problem, the internal classes are more than 'just' data members of Foo.

Comment: @AmiTavory A private namespace sounds interesting.. Do you have more information about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, unfortunately, impossible. §9.3/5:

> If the definition of a member function is lexically outside its class
>    definition, **the member function name shall be qualified by its
>    class name using the `::` operator**.

Since no class name exists, no out-of-class definitions for member functions are possible. The fact that GCC allows decltype-specifiers in this context is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

With `gcc` at least, you can do the trick using `decltype`:

```
int decltype(Foo::Sub1)::GetX() { return x; }
```

It is not standards compliant, though, as Columbo has already pointed out. So don't blame me, if a future version of `gcc` refuses to compile this. But we all now, that `gcc` has never been dogmatic about standards compliance, and that the `gcc` team has a strong tendency to keep language extensions, if they are both unambigous (which is clearly the case here) and useful to at least some programmers. Over the time, many of these `gcc` extensions have eventually become part of the standards.

Nonetheless, `clang` and probably most other compilers refuse this construct with the error message:

```
'decltype' cannot be used to name a declaration
```

But even `clang` can be tricked into accepting the `decltype` trick. We just need to do a `typedef`:

```
typedef decltype(Foo::Sub1) Sub1type;
int Sub1type::GetX() { return x; }
```

Of course, this is not much different to naming the unnamed classes. The advantage of the `typedef` solution might still be, that you can hide away the type names inside a private namespace.